# Component instance reference in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, component-based, serialization, entity-component-system

I'm creating a C++ script and I want to get a reference to a component instance.

For example, imagine that I want to get the player camera, which is a `UCameraComponent`. I would create a `UPROPERTY` like this:

```
 UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
 class UCameraComponent* PlayerCamera;
```

However, I can't assign it in the editor details panel like I would in Unity. I would expect to be able to drag and drop a Component from an Actor on the World Outline to this property but it seems that's not possible. Moreover, when clicking on the dropdown in the details panel, I don't have any available to choose from.

[image: Editor details for component reference]

From what I learned, it just isn't possible to do it this way and the Unreal way is to create a `UPROPERTY` to store a reference to the Actor and then get the component in runtime. Although this might work for most cases, it's still a bit memory inefficient since you might not need the Actor reference after getting the Component (yes, I know it's just a pointer, but still...). Plus, how would you handle multiple components of the same class in the same actor? I assume you have to loop over them and try to find the one you want, based on *a priori* knowledge of their order in the hierarchy or based on some of their known properties (maybe with tags)...

[image: Editor details for actor reference]

All of this seems kind of messy, so I ask you to please shed some light on what's the (best) Unreal workflow for setting component references.

Answer (score 2):

To do this in Unreal C++, inside the CPP file you need to do the following:

Make sure to include the header component:

**#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"**

Then in the class constructor:

**CameraComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject <UCameraComponent>("CameraComponent");**

From here you need to set up the attachment which is usually to the mesh if it's a character but can be attached to anything.

**CameraComponent->SetUpAttachment(GetMesh());**

Answer (score 0):

I come from Unity as well. The best I've come up with so far is to assign the variable in the construction script of the blueprint.